# Honeycomb ActionBar & Phone App

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have been writing my first app for a few weeks and today I realised that if we want to develop for Honeycomb and normal phones, we are supposed to package them together as one app rather than as two apps with different targets.

So I started a new project in Eclipse with a target of 2.1 (SDK level 7) and copied over my Java, XML and other resources from the old (Honeycomb oriented project) to the new (phone + tablet oriented) project.

All was going well until I hit a snag with the ActionBar code, in particular where I set the app icon to go to the main activity - it does not like this for some reason.

How are we supposed to write one app for both platforms? I thought it would be as simple as two versions of the layout and a few MINOR tweaks in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked closer at the new (phone + tablet oriented) project to see if there was anything I had missed that would be causing the problem.

It turns out in the androidmanifest.xml I had the wrong targetsdk and minsdk levels.

I have changed them to the correct ones:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

This change fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The best example I've found so far is the Google IO 2011 Schedule, which is freely available at http://code.google.com/p/iosched/.  The project was built specifically for this purpose - 1 apk provides a version of the app suitable for the phone and another for the tablets. Depending on how your app is structured, with some tweaking (major or minor depending on your perspective) the app can do pretty much anything for the two device platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The `ActionBar` was first introduced in Android 3.0

If you want your app to run with further versions, you'll have to check if the `ActionBar` is available (and then run the particular code) and if it's not, you'll have to come up with another solution (maybe your own implementation).

[Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) can be used to determine what Android version your app is running on.

Comment: In particular, you will need to isolate the Honeycomb-specific code references to a class that you *only* load when on Honeycomb -- otherwise, you will get `VerifyError` crashes at runtime. Here is a sample project demonstrating this for putting a custom `View` in the action bar: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC